# Construct an object with a given property from another object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that does to values what `Pick` generic does to types. That is given an object and a key, returns a new object containing only the property specified by that key, if it exists on the object, or `{}` otherwise.

I thought this would be simple enough:

```js
function pick<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): { [key in K]: T[K] } {
    return key in obj? { [key]: obj[key] } : {};
}
```

or

```js
function pick<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): Pick<T, K> {
    return key in obj? { [key]: obj[key] } : {};
}
```

(For my purposes I'm not concerned about picking multiple properties at a time, I need it to work with only one.)

However, the transpiler gives me an error on the return statement:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: T[K]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key in K]: T[K]; }'
```

I could suppress the error with a type assertion, but my question is if there is a way to make work without type assertions, and more specifically, why does it think the indexer is a string when `key` is defined as `K extends keyof T`?

Comment: This is a bug/limitation in TS described at [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948); the best thing to do is an assertion (although it's *not* correct to say `Pick<T, K>` because `K` might be a union and `Pick<T, K>` does not distribute across unions in `K`.  You could use [this type instead](https://tsplay.dev/m3BzLN)).  Does that fully address your question? If so, I'll write up an answer. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you, I think an answer on this would be useful. Looking at the links you posted I see that https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41779#issuecomment-737581197 is a good example of why this cannot/should not work like I'd expect it to

Comment: Also, is there a way to force `K` to be a _single_ literal out of all the possible keys because that's really what I need?

Comment: You could write the function to reject unions but that's more complicated and probably out of scope for the question (since it's harder to do that than not to do it).  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a longstanding bug in TypeScript filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) whereby [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) which are not single string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) types (such as [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) or [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) are widened all the way to `string`, which results in an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) that most people don't want.  It's actually kind of tricky to fix it, since the "obvious" `Record` type isn't appropriate in the face of unions.  A value like `{[Math.random()<0.5?"a":"b"]: 1}` is *not* of type `Record<"a" | "b", number>`.  Instead the type should probably *distribute* over unions in the key, like `Record<"a", number> | Record<"b", number>`.  Anyway it's been around for a long time and has yet to be properly addressed.

In the meantime then all you can do is work around it; the easiest workaround is to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) after double-checking that your type is right (if `K` happens to be a union, then `Pick<T, K>` isn't right for the reason laid out above, and again, you want something distributive like `{[P in K]: Pick<T, P>}[K]`):

```
function pick<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return { [key]: obj[key] } as { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: T[Q] } }[K];
}

const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: "two",
    c: false
}
const a = pick(obj, "a");
//    ^? const a: { a: number; }
const ab = pick(obj, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b");
//    ^? const ab: { a: number; } | { b: string; }
```

You mentioned not wanting to support unions in `K`, but this is difficult to do and probably not worth it.  Still, here's a possibility:

```
type NotUnion<T, U = T> = T extends any ? [U] extends [T] ? T : never : never;
function pick<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: NotUnion<K>) {
    return { [key]: obj[key] } as any as Pick<T, K>;
}

const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: "two",
    c: false
}
const a = pick(obj, "a"); // okay
//    ^? const a: Pick<{a: number, b: string; c: boolean}; "a">;
const ab = pick(obj, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"); // error!
// ----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

And note that you need type assertions either way.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEARAllALgJzQIwAU14BrJAbwCgkakAzAV2HkzQHtgkZiSAeAFSQQAHpgjAAJlAoBfADRIA0kNHipSEhACebOkn4A+ABRs8AKwBc+hZq1XFASgrVar7BEwNsnckgDatgC6VqZmAdqBSDJIINK+fgRIaJyKwRT+AIpJnARp-H4ZkdEyfqkA3C40MpSVSPAcWEihSAC8zq6uIFYAjHK1rnhWAESYAO5sQ30dtPBWdCAANlAQtdWu9cCNIK1cPCbmCkMgQw4VrgD0564AegD8tRtbeDvcpPtmCgCyIJgAFgB02BAkjYYCMTl4SAADP8AKxIW5II5DJDDPAnM60S43e6Uao1UCQWAIZAAOTYAFVgOxgERSO1aJgtDAyWxMFSaQIFBSdoZeSoxJJpMCtAj-BTIiJBeo-PxIojBFZgBAAG4QbCopDKtXYTE0RjMVgcXakAQCtRxeRKc1CjTaXT6YyhKz8GzaKzk9nUji8RQGJxUaY0dyebzpcJaNKhCNFGLC4Ci2JIOl8V1KAx6qI1dYNTBNcw7QNBrpIXr9WiDJFjCZTIOzeiLZarB65mIvPahQ7HU5IbFsEggLS1bG0O51VsllO8cgl4AMMB4dUKStYXDAADmZTqVjwbDYCwgwJkW+RGZbmzzIGebVeJHeXx+AKBILBEOhcLFyM1Q3RPex6uwNhsAAQmHK4AFpIKg6CYPAgwkAAPyQ5CUNQtD0OQsCkAAQWwdd53EPMHSZFkkAAclXZJ1zIpJpGANk4ygNB11APADyQTA2C4EAgUgMQNWI5lkDI7V1TI-4amqIA)